# No luck enabling developer mode on my Chromebook Pixel

Tags: chromebook

I'm trying to get my Chromebook Pixel to run in developer mode.  When i reach the recovery screen,  I press Control - D and nothing happens.  I press it over and over and nothing.  I purchased a C720P as a gift for someone,  and the Dev mode procedure worked on the first attempt !!! Really frustrating.  I just ran through the recovery process with a USB to see if that would help,  tried to invoke Dev Mode again and nothing.

Why wouldn't control - d work ?  any ideas ?

all help is really appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, this question was answered on the following thread, in case anyone else runs into this issue: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-dev/-aAusdRe0LY

To invoke Recovery mode, you hold down the ESC and Refresh keys and 
hold the Power button for at least 200ms (until the keyboard backlight 
comes on). If you don't hold it for long enough, then it won't work.  (Mike Frysinger)